# How can I have a sticky footer in CSS (Flexbox)?

Tags: css, flexbox

"How can I pin the footer to the bottom of the page"

I've been in a sticky situation with footers many times and I always end up with a different result.

What's the simplest way to have a sticky footer using CSS Flexbox?
I want this:
[image]
To look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If a web page has a `<header>`, `<main>` and a `<footer>` all inside of the `<body>`:

```
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

footer {
    background: grey;
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

Making the body flex column allows all items within to be stacked, the margin-top: auto is the magic piece here. It automatically fills any white space with a margin.

Credit goes to Stephanie Eckles: https://moderncss.dev/keep-the-footer-at-the-bottom-flexbox-vs-grid/